# why does this evaluate 2 as prime?

Tags: python

I've looked for the answer but not found it hence this question. I am confused by the following code from the python documentation (4.4 of tutorial) on the break statements. the code works fine, but why is 2 found to be a prime number? At at the first run it seems that n % x would be 2 % 2 == 0? What am I missing about how the ranges iterate?

```
for n in range(2, 100):
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
            break
    else:
        print(n, 'is prime')
```

other simlar code first excludes 2 as it is a 'special' prime and I cannot figure out how this code gets away with not doing that.

Comment: If `n` is 2, then 2 is not in `range(2, n)`. It is an empty range.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet, but 2 simply *is* a prime. No mathematical reference will tell you otherwise.

Comment: the `for x in range(2, n):` isn't getting any numbers for `x`, so not breaking, so going into the `else`..

Comment: Lets check if [2 is a prime number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2+a+prime+number%3F)!

Comment: thanks khelwood, makes perfect sense, but then what happens to that if statement? Is it found to be false because x has no value? Seems like that would throw an error.

Comment: The `if` statement is inside a loop that is executed for each `x` in the range. If the range is empty, it is executed zero times.

Comment: OK I see, an empty range moves on to the else, not entirely obvious and I assumed it was how that second range worked that I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is 2, then 2 is not in `range(2, n)`. It is an empty range.

`range(a,b)` runs through integers that are greater than or equal to `a`, and strictly less than `b`.

In your program, the statement

```
if n % x == 0:
    ...
```

is in a loop that is being run for each `x` in the given range. If the range is empty, the loop is executed zero times, so no factors are checked.

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` considers first limit as inclusive, but the second one as *exclusive*. Therefore when the first iteration runs `range(2, 2)` doesn't return any elements. Therefore no checks are done and 2 is deemed prime.